# Ubuntu - UnknownHostException when connecting to a PC, using a Socket in an Ad Hoc network

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ubuntu, adhoc

I have created a `FileSystemListener` that listens for files in a folder and sends them to a specified IP address. This has all been tested with a standard wireless network but I am getting an **unkownhostexception** when running it on an ad hoc network.

I was not sure if this was something I should ask on Superuser, or here, as I am not sure if it is an issue with my code or Ubuntu.

I can ping the other PC on the wireless network but I keep getting the above exception when connecting through java.

Not sure if it helps but here is the most basic SSCE I can think of:

```
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientTester {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket s  = new Socket("192.168.0.1", 4440);
   }
}
```

Anyone come across this before, wanted to see if it was a Java issue before I cross posted in Superuser.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the exception?  Also your report of what the problem is and the symptom are a little off.  UnknownHostException is the direct result of the JDK attempting name resolution.  Your sample includes an address only which doesn't attempt a name lookup.

Answer (score 0):

To compile correctly, `UnknownHostException` "must be caught or declared to be thrown."

For example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ClientTester {

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket s  = new Socket("192.168.0.1", 4440);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If this works with regular infrastructure mode, but not with ad-hoc mode you probably haven't configured the ad-hoc mode properly. Could you show us your /etc/network/interfaces config?